# Efficient call stack break technique

Tags: javascript, callstack

**Scenario**

I have a worker which processes items and propagates results through handler function invocation.

**Code**

At some points Worker internally invokes async methods between `processNextItem()` invocation and `resultHandler()` call back, which resets call stack:

```
function Worker(resultHandler) {
    this.processNextItem = function () {
        // some work
        ...

        // propagate result
        resultHandler(someResult);
    }
}   

var myResultHandler = function (result) {
    // Process result
    ...

    // Process next item
    worker.processNextItem();
};

var worker = new Worker(myResultHandler);

// Start working on first item
Worker.processNextItem();
```

But that is happening not often enough and sometimes I get *Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded*, because of recursive invocations:
`processNextItem() -> resultHandler() -> processNextItem() -> resultHandler() -> processNextItem() -> resultHandler() -> etc`.

To break it I've tried to use `setTimeout`:

```
this.processNextItem = function () {
    // some work
    ...

    // propagate result
    setTimeout(function () { resultHandler(someResult); }, 0);
}
```

But it is dramatically decreases performance (I have hundreds of items to process).

**Question**

Is there a way to break call stack by async invocation, but more efficient than `setTimeout`? Or should I count sync invocations manually and calling `setTimeout` every 1000 time or something?

---

**Solution for me: workaround**

Initially I solved this issue as @nepeo wrote: created a counter of sync callbacks and made every 1000 callback async. Which is obviously workaround as call stack limit differs from browser to browser (and probably from platform and version).

Eventually I've solved this issue by batching results:

```
function Worker(resultHandler) {
    this.processNextBatch = function () {
        // some ASYNC work
        ...

        // propagate results
        resultsHandler(someResults);
    }
}   

var myResultsHandler = function (results) {
    results.forEach(function (result) {
        // Process result
        ...
    });

    // Process next item
    worker.processNextBatch();
};

var worker = new Worker(myResultsHandler);

// Start working on first item
Worker.processNextBatch();
```

But that does not reply to this thread, and I'm still want to know answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm presuming the processing of this data is order dependant? If not I would try a non recursive call of your process function that invokes the handler, it would be much faster and you wouldn't have stack problems! Failing that your batch system is probably the least worst fix.

```
function _batch(callback){
    this.counter = 0;
    this.callback = callback;
    this.count = function(){
        if(this.counter >= 1000){
            setTimeout(callback,0);
            this.counter = 0;
            return false;
        }
        else
            this.counter++
        return true;
    }
}
```

Returning true if the result handler should recurse.

Or a potential restructure? It's kinda hard to know if this will work without more information.

```
var position = 0;
function process()
{
    while(1)
    {
        if(!bDataReady){
        setTimeout(process,5);
        break;}
        //process data
        //propagate data
        position ++;
        if(bComplete)
            break
    }
}
```

Comment: Data is order dependent, indeed. That batching system is exactly how I solved it for now. Thanks, but that looks more like workaround.

Comment: Sounds like a real pain, it is really a workaround but i think it may honestly be the fastest way unless you can restructure the sequence to be non order dependant. I came up with a few ideas like creating a quasi stack thread using setInterval but I imagine it will have the same performance issues. Alternatively you could process the data via a server depending on the latency you require?

Comment: I'm not sure, how non ordered data can help in this case. Could you please explain a bit? I'm more interested in understanding how problems like this should be resolved in general, as they should be common in callback base language, than solving my current case (as it is already working).

Comment: well in a non ordered case you could initiate each process call in a basic loop, then if one process required a certain piece of data you can use setTimeout() to recurse that call until the data has loaded. Obviously if the next item is dependant on the previous being completed then having an async call like that could just break it somewhat. As for other languages JS is somewhat stunted by the lack of multithreading and sleeps, so we have to use messy callbacks functions like setTimeout().